# Accessing Variables Through a Server (Java)

Tags: java, networking

So I'm making a basic chat program and I have a hosting server and a client. The client does connect, but I'm curious as to how to get the variables from the client and add them to the server side.

If that's hard to visualize, I'm asking people to log in via client... when they type their username and password into the fields and hit "login", their information is stored into a variable, client sided. How Would I access that variable server sided?

Comment: well, if you have a client and a server, then you have a communication link. the client send something and the server get that on the other side. Is that what you're asking? (sorry, i really didn't get it)

Answer (score 0):

You can't "access" the variables in the sense that you would call `client.getPassword()` on the client instance of a class.

That said, there are a lot of ways to transfer data from a client to a server in general and in Java in particular.  The most common use is via an HTTP `POST` request (HTTPS, to be specific, if you're sending authentication data), but you could use a TCP/IP socket as well.

I know that answer is vague, but there a a number of ways to accomplish what you're asking.  If you post code samples of what you've tried or what's not working, people can answer specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

With Java you can serialized a java object and send it over the internet.  Have a look at this: http://ta.cnci.org/basicirc